# How to call a method from vue template with get data

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I create a Method in vue call this Method in template then show data in my console.log but i not get data in template.

My vue method:

```
<script>
export default {
    methods:{
        getProducts:function(storeID){            
            axios.get('/axios/storeproducts/'+storeID, {
                params: {
                    storeID: storeID,
                }
            })
            .then(function (response) {
                console.log(response.data);
               return response.data;
            })
            .catch(function (error) {
                console.log(error);
            });
        }
    },
}
</script>
```

My template:

```
<ul>
    <li v-for="product in getProducts(store.id)" :key="product.id">{{product.id}}</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Where is this method (getProducts )called?

Comment: <template> <ul>
                        <li v-for="product in getProducts(store.id)" :key="product.id">{{product.id}}</li>
                    </ul> </template>

Comment: Inside the template

Comment: see the solution I've provided

Answer (score 0):

Please change your code to this:

```
<script>
export default {
    data(){
        return {
            products: []
        };
    },
    methods:{
                getProducts:function(storeID){            
                    axios.get('/axios/storeproducts/'+storeID, {
                        params: {
                            storeID: storeID,
                        }
                    })
                    .then(function (response) {
                        console.log(response.data);
                       this.products = response.data;
                    })
                    .catch(function (error) {
                        console.log(error);
                    });
                }
            },
    },
    mounted(){
        //this shoud call after load the 'store.id';
        this.getProducts(this.store.id);
    }
}
</script>
```

and template to:

```
<ul>
    <li v-for="product in products" :key="product.id">{{product.id}}</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: I have multiple stores. Stores sell a variety of products. You should see a list of which category products are sold with the store listing.

Comment: So my template <div v-for="store in stores" :key="store.id"> <ul> <li v-for="product in getProducts(store.id)">{{product.id}}</li> </ul> </div>

Comment: In this case you should have a two-dimensional array `products`; and should add like following code: `this.$set(this.products, index,response.data)`

Comment: I have a store array for show Store list. and also show store product categories with this list.

Answer (score 0):

A more subtle approach to using methods via async in a template is this

1. in the created/mounted function call your method - this is useful for async calls

   `<script>
      export default {
      data: function(){
         return {
            products: []
         }
      },
      created: function(){
         // make async request here or in mounted
         this.getProducts();
      },
      methods:{
          getProducts:(){
            //Get store id via props or route query or params
           axios.get('/axios/storeproducts/'+storeID, {
                       params: {
                           storeID: storeID,
                       }
                   })
                   .then(function (response) {
                       console.log(response.data);
                      this.products = response.data;
                   })
                   .catch(function (error) {
                       console.log(error);
                   });
          }
      }
    }
    </script>`
2. Finally, use the property in template

   `<ul>
      <li v-for="product in products" :key="product.id">{{product.id}}</li>
    </ul>`

Hope this helps

Comment: I have multiple stores. Stores sell a variety of products. You should see a list of which category products are sold with the store listing.  
So my template <div v-for="store in stores" :key="store.id"> <ul> <li v-for="product in getProducts(store.id)">{{product.id}}</li> </ul> </div>

Comment: if you have multiple stores... im sure all there info are displayed simulateously...create a trigger to call the getProduct method on click. Is that what you are looking at